# DB returns empty list when I try to retrieve sorted rows

Tags: sqlite, flask

I'm new to flask. I'm trying to sort rows in my DB according to selected option in the form. The problem is that, I get empty list instead of list of tuples with rows data in it. Though both post request and my DB are not empty and my SQL request is working with my current DB in sqlitebrowser.

routes.py:

```
@bp.route('/poll-process', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def process():
    form =  ChoiceForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        select = request.form.get('sel')  
        if select:
            print(select)
            db = get_db()
            res = db.execute(
            '''SELECT username, sex, city, emotion, month, poll_time
                FROM poll
                JOIN author
                    ON poll.author_id = author.id
                ORDER BY sex ASC''', (select)                  
            ).fetchall()
            print(res) 
            db.close
    return render_template('process.html', form=form)
```

shema.sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS author;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS poll;

CREATE TABLE `author` (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `username`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `sex`   TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `poll` (
    `poll_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `city`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `emotion`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    `month` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `poll_time` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `author_id`   INTEGER,   
  FOREIGN KEY(`author_id`) REFERENCES `author`
);
```

process.html:

```
<form method="post">
  <!-- select -->
  <div class="form-group mt-4">  
    <h2>Choose criteria to sort</h2>
    <select class="custom-select" name="sel">        
      {% for field in form.sel %}
        <option>{{ field }}</option>    
      {% endfor %}      
    </select>
    ...
    {{form.submit(class="btn btn-primary")}}
</form>
```

Here is my output:

```
 * Serving Flask app "flaskapp" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 231-471-963
poll_time
[]
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2019 21:16:59] "POST /poll-process HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your query in `routes.py`

```py
@bp.route('/poll-process', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def process():
    form =  ChoiceForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        select = request.form.get('sel')  
        if select:
            print(select)
            db = get_db()
            res = db.execute(
            '''SELECT username, sex, city, emotion, month, poll_time
                FROM poll
                JOIN author
                ON poll.author_id = author.id
                ORDER BY %s''' % (select,)                  
            ).fetchall()
            print(res) 
            db.close
    return render_template('process.html', form=form)
```